# Hangman Program not updating word after letter is correctly guessed

Tags: java

So, I'm currently making a Hangman class that is essentially the entire game but run on a different program that calls the class. I'm having trouble with a certain method that is supposed to update the hidden word by adding the correct letter to a string of characters (symbols) when it is right, and It doesn't seem to update whenever I put put in output. I'm not that good of a coder.

```
/**
 * Displays the guess,specifically the word replaced by characters to make it look hidden, example 'money' = '*****'
 * @output - essentially the word replaced by characters 
 */
public void displayGuess() {
    guess = "";
    int length = word.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<length;i++) {
        guess += String.valueOf(symbol);
    }
    System.out.println("Guess is " + guess);
    count++;
}




/**
 * Updates the hidden word if the letter is guessed correctly then it replaces a character in the word with the correct letter
 * @param a - the letter guessed by the user input
 * @output should output the updated guess word, so example, guessing the letter 'a'  when the word is apple should give you a**** 
 */

public void updateWord(char a) {
    char [] newWord = new char [word.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i<word.length();i++) {
        if(word.charAt(i)==a) {
            newWord[i] = a;
            
        
            
        }
            else {
                newWord[i] = guess.charAt(i);
                
            
        }
        

    }
    String newGuess = String.valueOf(newWord);

}
```

So the output I'm supposed to get is
[image: Expected Output]

However, I'm getting:
[image: Current Output]

The output doesn't seem to be adding correct words to the string and I have no clue how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `updateWord` just creates a new `String` which is never used again.

```
String newGuess = String.valueOf(newWord);
```

You need to change this method so that it returns the String `newGuess`

```
public String updateWord(char a)
```

Comment: DIdn't really work, same output, changed the method to public String and added a return newGuess line and same output.

Comment: well you gotta use the value that is returned.

Comment: I'm using two programs to run this, so the one currently with this code is essentially doing all of the work while the other one calls all the methods in the class. updateWord isn't supposed to return anything, it's supposed to output it.

Comment: *updateWord isn't supposed to return anything, it's supposed to output it.* - so where in `updateWord` is there any output??